# DeleteDatabase function dose not delete database in SQLite

Tags: xamarin.android, android-sqlite

This database exists: user.db3

I want to delete this database.

But DeleteDatabase function dose not delete database.

```
this.DeleteDatabase("user.db3");
string dpPath1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "user.db3");
if (dpPath1.IndexOf("user.db3") < 0)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "user.db3 does not exist", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the code below to delete the database file.

```
//Delete
    private void Button_Clicked_6(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(_databasePath);
        try
        {
            if (fi.Exists)
            {                    
                db.Close();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                fi.Delete();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            fi.Delete();
        }
    }
```

_databasePath:

```
 static readonly string _databasePath = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "user.db3");
```

db:

```
 static SQLiteConnection db;
```

Comment: Hello. This is true?  `System.IO.FileInfo fi1 = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "user.db3"));` `if (fi1.Exists) { if (db != null){db.Close();GC.Collect();GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();}fi1.Delete();}` `if (!fi1.Exists){Toast.MakeText(this, "OK", ToastLength.Short).Show();}`

Comment: Yes, it works for me. The database could be deleted with the code i provided.

Comment: `this.DeleteDatabase("user.db3")` does not work for me.